# Thymeleaf: How to get selected item on click

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to call a method with the clicked object as a param.

Problem: on every reload or button press the method is called for every element.

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${chessBoard}" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr th:each="i, iter1: *{board}">
            <td th:each="item, iter2: ${i}">
                <button th:onclick="${chessBoard.selected(item)}" th:text="${item.text}"></button>
            </td>
        <tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the onclick method in your form to submit a parameter.
You can simply pass a parameter to the controller with a RequestedParam annotation in your controller.
It will be something like:

```
<form th:action="@{/}" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr th:each="i: ${board}">
        <td th:each="item: ${i}">
            <button name="item" th:value="${item.id}" th:text="${item.text}"/>
        </td>
    <tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

and in your controller:

```
@PostMapping (path = "/")
public String test(Model model, @RequestParam(name = "item") int id) {
  System.out.println(id);
}
```

A second option is to use an attribute that you add to your model and you get back in your controller with something like:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute ChessBoard chessBoard, Model model) {...}
```

Html will be something like

```
<form th:action="@{/}" th:object="${chessBoard}" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr th:each="i: ${board}">
      <td th:each="item: ${i}">
        <button th:field="*{id}" th:value="${item.id}" th:text="${item.text}"/>
      </td>
   <tr>
 </table>
</form>
```